# Having issues with my websites htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewritecond, plesk

I recently uploaded a PHP theme on my server.  It's working fine on any other sections except my home page.  For example, when accessing `www.mywebsite.com/anything` the theme is working but when on homepage `www.mywebsite.com` the server's default page is shown.

I was playing with the htacess RewriteEngine and it was working in some cases but probably not correct.  This is what I have so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Options -Multiviews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?a=$1  [QSA,NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /new/404.php
</IfModule>
```

This is making my home page work, but the title is not showing it's saying "Page Not Found" on the title.  The page is working and all I'm changing is the two RewriteCond above.  They were set to `{REQUEST_FILENAME}` but that made my website homepage not work and show the default server page.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear in your question if the correct PHP files are being hit. Assuming the syntax of your `.htaccess` is correct:

Your `RewriteRule` is indicating your `index.php` as the receiver for any files and directories that do not exist, with the path (I believe) being sent to `$_GET['a']`... it is up to your `index.php` to detect and handle this appropriately.

`ErrorDocument` is a separate mechanism and once again, if the `404.php` is being hit it is up to it to e.g. `header('HTTP/1.1 404 File Not Found')` and then output HTML that indicates a page not found.

Comment: this is what i have found in my index.php

<?php
include("includes/htaccessConfig.php");
$app = new App();
$app->run();
?>

Comment: So this is an application someone else wrote? Which application is it? Is there any documentation on how to accomplish this redirect?